# Go template to struct

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a Go template that should resolve to a struct. How can I convert the `bytes.Buffer`result from template execute function back to the `struct`. [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/LY5ZB_aizv)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "text/template"
)

type Data struct {
    Age      int
    Username string
    SubData  SubData
}
type SubData struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    s := SubData{Name: "J. Jr"}
    d := Data{Age: 26, Username: "HelloWorld", SubData: s}
    tmpl := "{{ .SubData }}"
    t := template.New("My template")
    t, _ = t.Parse(string(tmpl))
    buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
    t.Execute(buffer, d)
    fmt.Println(buffer)

    // writing
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(buffer)
    err := enc.Encode(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("encode error:", err)
    }

    // reading
    buffer = bytes.NewBuffer(buffer.Bytes())
    e := new(SubData)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(buffer)
    err = dec.Decode(e)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("decode error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(e, err)
}
```

Comment: This seems entirely like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).The OP's comment below reinforces this perception.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. This is plain simply impossible.

But why on earth would anybody want to do something like this? Why don't you just send your `Data` directly via gob and decode it directly? Why creating a textual representation which you gob?

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it would be possible. I am trying to write a JSON-Go Template layout. so I can do `{x:{i1:"1",i2:"2"},y:"{{ .X }}"}`. This way `y` can have a reference to `X` in template after parsing JSON.

Comment: @aminjam: Go templates are entirely the wrong tool for you, then. Just use... a struct.